# How do I write excel file to optional file location?

Tags: java, excel, gwt

I am using GWT for a project. On button click I want to save an excel file to a user defined file location. Is it possible to prompt the user for the file location to save to?

So instead of saving in C:\New folder\ I want the user to choose..

```
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\New folder\\purchase-order.xlsx");
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
```

The front end involving the button looks like this.

```
Button getPurchaseOrderForAllPickedItems = new Button("Get Purchase Order for all items selected", new ClickHandler() {

public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> exportFile = extracted();
    sendListToServerForExport(exportFile);
}
```

The sendListToServerForExport method looks like this:

```
private void sendListToServerForExport(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> exportMap) {

    if (stockPriceSvc == null) {
        stockPriceSvc = GWT.create(PurchaseOrderService.class);
    }

    AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {

            Window.alert(result);

        }

    };
    stockPriceSvc.createExcelExportFile(exportMap, callback);
}
```

The method in the service implementation looks like this:

```
public String createExcelExportFile(
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> exportMap) {
    controller.createFileToExport(exportMap);

    return "Succes";
}
```

Comment: i have a question to you! RPC is used for Database only? Thanks!

Comment: If it is saving the file, it is the browser that is not asking for the file location. I doubt you can override this functionality in the widget. You would have to have the user configure their browser to prompt to save to a specific location. Just so we are on the same page here is how to configure it for firefox. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file

Comment: As a heads up I have never seen anything like that nor would I imagine it would exist due to the fact that js has very little access to the filesystem. There is no header to specify a save location either so I am pretty sure it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are leaving some major detail out it should be really simple. Just prompt the user to enter the location and use a scanner or a prompt to get the input as a string. I will post some example code in a minute here...

```
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class ReadConsoleScanner { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        System.out.println("Enter something here : ");       
        String sWhatever;   
        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in); 
        sWhatever = scanIn.nextLine();   
        scanIn.close(); 
        System.out.println(sWhatever); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: thx. It is a web application. OnClick I want a popup so that the user can choose the save location.

Comment: Oh ok ok so are you using javascript on the front end?

Comment: Yes, front end is compiled to javascript. Using RPC call to server side where the code for the create excel file is found

Comment: Alright can you post more of the code such as the code involving the button in question?

Comment: Can you post the sendListToServerForExport code for me?

Comment: Alright so what have you tried for input? The prompt(String, String) method is what you have tried I assume?

Comment: I don't follow. In which class?

Comment: We are sending an RPC to the service implementation method which calls our controller class which then calls out ExportToExcel class which is where we have the create excel file method and code

Comment: The Window class which can be seen at:     http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#prompt(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)